# Internal hard drive runs faster in an enclosure then plugged into the case

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

Long story short: My OS is on an SDD, I use a secondary hard drive for storage. Secondary hard drive fails, backup data and put it on a new laptop sized HDD I bought. Runs horribly, have to put it through 3 chkdsk's running off my laptop to work at all.

Now's the interesting part. When it's plugged into my case, SATA and all that, it runs really poorly. explorer.exe crashing and restarting all the time, takes ages to load into the file browser, generally bad. I take it out and put it into an external hard drive dock, plug it in through USB, runs pretty well. Minus the whole USB connection thing, it's responsive and everything loads like it's supposed to, no crashes.

There are a few things that could be causing this. 1) It's a laptop hard drive and doesn't fit well into my desktop. Only one of the screws aligns and I don't have a 2.5'-3.5' adapting dock (yet). I know it would be subject to more vibration, but it doesn't seem like it would cause these kinds of slowdowns to me. Second possibility is the SATA cable is in bad shape, which is possible. It squeezes really awkwardly into a plug right behind my giant GPU and kinda squishes into itself, and it's too short to reach a more open plug while still getting to the hard drive dock.

So the basic question is, do either of these two possibilities explain my situation? Do you have any other ideas as to what could be causing it? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Unless your booting to the disk while its mounted over a USB connection what you experienced is normally.  If I were to hazard a guess the drive letter was even different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrong BIOS configuration could cause some trouble... If you feel comfortable with it, try poking around in the BIOS menu for your SATA settings. Be sure though that you do not change anything if you don't know what is what (you can google most of it).

Hard disk not fitting in casing shouldn't be causing this much trouble indeed. Though you'd be better off just leaving it unfixed than having it fixed in a skewed/contorted way.

Then of course your sata port on the mobo could be faulty. Do you only have 2 ports available? That's not a lot... What motherboard do you have? If you have multiple, try other ports. If you only have two sata ports, you could try and switch the two cables and see if you have trouble booting. If that's the case, it's your cables. If after the switch you still have the same trouble, it's not.

Also, a new SATA cable costs next to nothing so it wouldn't hurt to give that a try. Though in my experience SATA cables really either work or don't work... But who knows.

Comment: I have 3, maybe 4 SATA ports, problem is the cables I have are dinky short and I have to do hard drive gymnastics to make them fit at all. Honestly, longer SATA cables are long overdue anyway. I'll go buy some tomorrow and let you know how they work out. Also, what kind of BIOS settings do you figure could cause this kind of reaction? From my experience there aren't many configuration options related to hard drives and if you get'em wrong you can't boot at all.

Comment: Well, there may be optimization options like caching, en-/disabling of sata2/sata3, power saving, IDE vs. AHPI mode, en-/disabling of Native Command Queuing (NCQ), things like that. You could try saving your current options and setting everything to "default" or "optimized" or "failsafe" or some other preset.

Btw, I think all my sata cables are 45 cm. I wish they were shorter.

Comment: By the way, the world won't explode if you just take out your drives and lay them on a stack of CD cases for a couple of minutes while testing so they're close enough to quickly test your ports/sata cables :) I think it's worth your time to determine whether it's a) your cables, b) your ports or c) your mainboard. Judging from the fact that there's no access problems when mounting over USB, I'd hazard a guess that it's not your actual drives themselves.

Comment: Sorry for the slew of comments. But by the way, we're hunting for hardware troubleshooting now. What you may want to try is to boot from some sort of boot CD (like the "Try Ubuntu" from the Ubuntu installation CD which you can download and burn for free). That automatically mounts your drives too, and you can try and browse your drives, test copying some large directory, whatever. If that runs perfectly, it may also be something weird in your current OS installation.

Comment: I got the new SATA cables earlier and plugged it into a different slot, and it's working fine. So either the cable I used was faulty or the plug was. Or it was just poorly seated, not really sure yet. But anyway, thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: No problem friend, in this time more than ever we should help each other wherever we possibly can. Enjoy, and have a great weekend! :)